# transfer Optitrack-NatNet-Quaternion to a Rotation of a 3-D Model in a libgdx Scene with scaled axes

Tags: android, 3d, rotation, libgdx, quaternions

We track a Tablet with Markers and the Optitrack System. Therefore we use a JNI Wrapper to have access on functions of the NatNet SDK. After receiving the Position data on the server we stream(real time) it back to the client- the tablet itself and render an Augmented Reality Scene with the libgdx framework. The Target Platform is Android.
Here is some sample data we are receiving (7 values: x,y,z, qx, qy, qz, qw):

> -0,465436 0,888108 -0,991635 0,331507 0,091413 -0,379475 0,858921
>
> -0,438584 0,888583 -0,982334 0,356608 0,092872 -0,364935 0,855002
>
> -0,414451 0,892762 -0,973772 0,365460 0,096244 -0,348293 0,857828
>
> -0,394074 0,900471 -0,963359 0,365230 0,109444 -0,323559 0,865990

The first three values describe the position in the room. We scale the values of the z-axis by the factor of 3 to have a autentic translation from the small values we are receiving to the size we need in our render libgdx scene on the tablet itself and it works fine! The last 4 values are for the rotation of the tracked tablet as an quaternion. This is really new to me as I never worked with quaternion before.
Libgdx supports rotations in a 3D scene with quaternions, but after handing the values over to the concrete modelInstance the rotation is totally unexpected and full of errors. Here is the important code:

```
    //gets the rotation of the latest received rigidbody position data 
    //and stores them into a libgdx Quaternion
    Quaternion rotation = rigidBody.getQuat();

    modelInst.transform.rotate(rotation);

    ...

    public Quaterion getQuat(){
       float qx = rigidBody.qx;
       float qy = rigidBody.qy;
       float qz = rigidBody.qy;
       float qw = rigidBody.qw;

       Quaternion rot = new Quaternion(qx, qy, qz, qw);
       return rot;
    }
```

Looks obvious to me so far. But is does not work. When I rotate the tablet it tranlates too and rotates in wrong and unexpected directions without translating the tablet. I've been looking for solutions for a week now. First I tried different permutations of the parameters which I hand over to the libgdx Quaternion class. The rotation values seem to be in a relative(local) form in a right handed coordinate system. At least this is whats written in the official NatNet User Guide on page 12:
[NatNet User Guide](http://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/static/documents/NatNet%20API%20User%20Guide.pdf)
. I think libgdx uses absolute Quaternions, but I couldnt figure it out for sure. If this would be the case...how could I transform relative Quaternions to absolute ones? Or maybe it has to do something with our scaling of the z-Axis values?
We appreciate ervery help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd definitely remove the z-axis scaling and fix the rotation issue first. The relative v.s. global is only relevant for the Euler angle conversion. However you need to know whether the (quaternion) rotation is applied before or after the translation.

Comment: First we rotate and then translate. This should be the right order. I've removed the scaling of the z-Axis. Furthermore I only apply the rotation(no translation) of the modelInstance for testing, but the behavior does not seem to change. The rotation around the z-axis works fine, but the rotation around the x and y axis always comes with some translation. It looks like some kind of offset from the given axis it should rotate around. like a satellite rotating around a fixed point...